# Filter JSON по имени. TelegramBot

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, filter, lambda

Столкнулся с проболемой по фильтру JSON данных.
Поставлена задача(в учебных целях)

> Вот, делай фильтр по юзерам и выводи по совпадению в имени и фамилии кол-во найденных. Потом по кнопке показать первого выводи в чат всю инфу о нём в форматировании:

```
-Имя,
-логин,
-телефон,
-геопозиция(можно метку в ТГ передавать в картинке, есть дока по ТГ),
-ссылку на сайт,
-название компании.
```

> Потом кнопку «показать следующего»,
> вот тут прокачаешься

По боту вроде вопросов нет, сделал кнопки, вывод юзеру данных и т.д,
но сделал через "костыли".

https://gist.github.com/vadimpopovnice/742f6ed8c265bcfcd0d996a9d98e58b1

ссылка на то, как я попробовал решить задачу.

Мне подсказали, мол:

> Больше на дичь похоже)
> Тебе нужно один список фильтровать, ты можешь не знать все значения.
> 1-е у тебя есть имя из сообщения
> 2-е у тебя есть список.
> Тебе нужно фильтр по сообщению написать и всё
> без ифов

Вроде бы так:

```
listFiltered = listUsers.filter(lambda x: message in x["name"] )
```

> и потом нужно вывести размер списка

```
len(listFiltered)
```

В конце добавили, мол:

> x - это элемент списка. То есть x будет вызван столько раз, сколько элементов в списке. И по этому условию в скобках фильтр решает добавлять этот элемент в список как тот, который соответствует условию фильтра

Помогите разобраться, может кто-то сталкивался или есть идеи по реализации, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Почитайте, например, про встроенную функцию `filter`: https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-filter/

Comment: Спасибо (за редакцию тоже), попробую разобратся.